# Upgrade to 5.43.0 fails: DB Error: constraint violation on "Make mapping field foreign key cascade delete"

Tags: upgrade

I tried to upgrade our CiviCRM installation to 5.43.0 but on upgrade script an error appears:

```
Type    DB_Error
Code    -3
Message DB Error: constraint violation
Mode    16
UserInfo    ALTER TABLE civicrm_mapping_field ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mapping_field_mapping_id` FOREIGN KEY (`mapping_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_mapping`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`civi_crm`.`#sql-25b0_7f`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mapping_field_mapping_id` FOREIGN KEY (`mapping_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_mapping` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
DebugInfo   ALTER TABLE civicrm_mapping_field ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mapping_field_mapping_id` FOREIGN KEY (`mapping_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_mapping`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`civi_crm`.`#sql-25b0_7f`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mapping_field_mapping_id` FOREIGN KEY (`mapping_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_mapping` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]
```

The error shown:

```
PEAR_Exception: DB Error: constraint violation in \sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\pear\pear-core-minimal\src\PEAR.php on line 922
- DB_Error: DB Error: constraint violation in unknown on line unknown
```

The backtrace:

```
0   CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error))   \sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\pear\pear-core-minimal\src\PEAR.php:922
1   PEAR_Error->__construct('DB Error: constr…', -3, 16, Array, ' ALTER T…')     \sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\pear\db\DB.php:997
2   DB_Error->__construct(-3, 16, Array, ' ALTER T…')    \sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\pear\pear-core-minimal\src\PEAR.php:575
3   PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), null, -3, 16, Array, ' ALTER T…', 'DB_Error', true)     \sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\pear\pear-core-minimal\src\PEAR.php:223
4   PEAR->__call('raiseError', Array)    \sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\pear\db\DB\common.php:1928
5   DB_common->raiseError(-3, null, null, ' ALTER T…', '1452 ** Cannot a…')  \sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\pear\db\DB\mysqli.php:936
6   DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()    \sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\pear\db\DB\mysqli.php:406
7   DB_mysqli->simpleQuery(' ALTER T…')  \sites\all\modules\civicrm\vendor\pear\db\DB\common.php:1234
8   DB_common->query(' ALTER T…')    \sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php:2696
9   DB_DataObject->_query(' ALTER T…')   \sites\all\modules\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php:1829
10  DB_DataObject->query(' ALTER T…')    \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php:468
11  CRM_Core_DAO->query(' ALTER T…', false)  \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php:1619
12  CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery(' ALTER T…', Array, true, null, false, false)     \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Upgrade\Incremental\php\FiveFortyThree.php:176
13  CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_php_FiveFortyThree::alterMappingFK(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))    \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Queue\Task.php:74
14  CRM_Queue_Task->run(Object(CRM_Queue_TaskContext))   \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Queue\Runner.php:201
15  CRM_Queue_Runner->runNext(true)  \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Queue\Page\AJAX.php:36
16  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::{closure}()     \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Queue\ErrorPolicy.php:89
17  CRM_Queue_ErrorPolicy->call(Object(Closure))     \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Queue\Page\AJAX.php:38
18  CRM_Queue_Page_AJAX::runNext()   \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php:279
19  CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array)  \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php:69
20  CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array)  \sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Core\Invoke.php:36
21  CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)   \sites\all\modules\civicrm\drupal\civicrm.module:458
22  civicrm_invoke('upgrade', 'queue', 'ajax', 'runNext')    \includes\menu.inc:527
23  menu_execute_active_handler()    \index.php:21
24  {main}
```

The error happens on my local machine as well on the dev server and it happens when calling the upgrade script via drush as well as in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do `select f.* from civicrm_mapping_field f left join civicrm_mapping m on f.mapping_id = m.id where m.id is null`. I suspect you have some fields where the mapping_id points to a mapping that doesn't exist and that query will locate them.

If that query does show you some rows, then since the mapping doesn't exist anyway you could just delete those rows.